# c# sorting list <DateTime> and inserting to database

Tags: c#, list, datetime, sorting

I´ve come to a total stop with my program and im in need of some help.

I got an xml file with customer billings and billing dates. This file has about 4000 billing dates. What i want is to sort them so the once that is in a range of a period date of `2010-04-01 - 2011-03-31` adds to a table column named period1. And the other dates goes to period2 that is `2011-04-01 - 2012-03-31`.

Ive been testing and testing this solution in diffrent ways but it wont work. Im adding all the dats to a list named dates. And trying:

```
if (dates.All(date => date >= startDatePeriod1 && date <= stopDatePeriod1))
{
    adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1Query(// insert to database));
}
else if (dates.All(date => date >= startDatePeriod2 && date >= stopDatePeriod2))
{
    adapterBonus.InsertPeriod2Query(// insert to database));
}

startDatePeriod1 = 2010-04-01
stopDatePeriiod1 = 2011-03-31
```

and so on

Comment: What do you mean by "adds to a table column named period1"? Increments the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Enumerable.All` extension method returns true if *every* element in the sequence verifies the condition. If `dates` contains dates in both periods, none of the ifs will run, because both calls to `Enumerable.All` will return false.

I'm not sure what you mean by "adds to a table column named period1", but if you mean to count all the dates in each period, use `Enumerable.Count`:

```
int period1Count = dates.Count(date => date >= startDatePeriod1 && date <= stopDatePeriod1);
int period2Count = dates.Count(date => date >= startDatePeriod2 && date <= stopDatePeriod2);
adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1Query(period1Count);
adapterBonus.InsertPeriod2Query(period2Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing, is the following:
Check whether **ALL** dates are in period one. If so, insert them into period 1 in the database. If not, check whether **ALL** dates are in period two and insert them into period 2 in the database.

You want to do the following:

```
foreach (var period1Date in dates.Where(date => date >= startDatePeriod1 && 
                                                date <= stopDatePeriod1))
{
    adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1Query(// insert period1Date to database));
}
foreach (var period2Date in dates.Where(date => date >= startDatePeriod2 && 
                                                date <= stopDatePeriod2))
{
    adapterBonus.InsertPeriod2Query(// insert period2Date to database));
}
```

BTW: I fixed an error in your second condition. It should be `date <= stopDatePeriod2` instead of `date >= stopDatePeriod2`!

Answer (score 1):

All return a boolean specifying whether all elements satisfy a condition. What you need is a Where() to extract those you need.

Something like:

```
adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1Query(dates.Where(date => date >= startDatePeriod1 && date <= stopDatePeriod1));
adapterBonus.InsertPeriod2Query(dates.Where(date => date >= startDatePeriod2 && date <= stopDatePeriod2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var period1Dates = dates.Where(date => date >= startDatePeriod1 && date <= stopDatePeriod1);
var period2Dates = dates.Where(date => date >= startDatePeriod2 && date >= stopDatePeriod2);

foreach(var date in period1Dates)
{                          adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1Query(// insert to database)); }
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way to do this is doing a

```
startDatePeriod1 = 2010-04-01;
stopDatePeriod1 = 2011-03-01;   
startDatePeriod2 = 2011-04-01;
stopDatePeriod2 = 2012-03-01;

foreach(DateTime d in dates) {
    if (d => startDatePeriod1 && d <= startDatePeriod1) {
        adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1Query(// insert to database));
    } else if(d => startDatePeriod2 && d <= stopDatePeriod2) {
        adapterBonus.InsertPeriod2Query(// insert to database));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like you just need a simple query for each bonus period, something like ...

```
var period1Dates = date.Where(date => date >= startDate1 && date <= stopDate1);
var period2Dates = date.Where(date => date >= startDate2 && date <= stopDate2);

adapterBonus.InsertPeriod1(period1Dates);
adapterBonus.InsertPeriod2(period2Dates);
```

As Daniel says, you're checking if all the dates are within each period, which it sound like will never be true, so nothing will be happening.